# My udev Rule do not trigger when USB driver is connected

Tags: linux, usb, udev, raspbian

I trying to run a script each time a USB drive is connected to the Raspberry PI by using udev rules, but cannot get it to work.

I have created a file in:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/85-usbthumb.rules
```

Containing:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/home/pi/updatePres.sh"
```

If I call the script directly (see below) it is executed correctly:

```
. /home/pi/updatePres.sh
```

When I connect a USB-drive a "Removable medium is inserted"-dialog is shown, but my script do not run. What have I done wrong? Are there any way for me to debug why this is not working?

Comment: What makes you think that your script doesn't run? Why couldn't it be an error in your script (e.g. it depends on some environment variable that isn't set when run from udev)? Note that to run a script, the command is `/home/pi/updatePres.sh`, not `. /home/pi/updatePres.sh`: the `.` command causes the script to be executed by the current shell, not executed as a separate program.

Comment: Is `/home/pi/updatePres.sh` executable? Does it correctly start with `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`? If so, add `exec >/tmp/updatePres.log 2>&1; set -x` as the second line of the script, try again, and post the content of the script and of `/tmp/updatePres.log`.

Comment: @Gilles Right now the script in /home/pi/updatePres.sh looks as follows:

'#!/bin/bash exec >/tmp/updatePres.log 2>&1; set -x /usr/bin/killall soffice.bin . /startPresScript.sh'

Comment: @Gilles When I connect an USB memory stick no file is created in '/tmp/updatePres.log'. If I run '/home/pi/updatePres.sh' from the terminal using './updatePres.sh' the file is created and everything seems to run as intended.